# How to create a page to change login password? (Oracle APEX 21.1)

Tags: oracle-apex

my professora :D

I want to create a page what logged in users can change their passwords.

User ID is taken from `APP_USER`. And I want to update the registration information with the password entered in the text box `:P9901_NEW_PASSWORD`.

Can I implement this with the standard functionality in Oracle APEX?
Or tell me how to encrypt the table to be updated and the password?

Thanks for your kindness to read this question :)

Comment: you should mention your current authentication method

Comment: Thank you for your responce!!
Login page's processe say, ```apex_authentication.login``` :D

Comment: it's under Shared Components/Authentication Schemes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the authentication is apex authentication (usernames/passwords are defined in apex), then the password can be changed using the `APEX_UTIL` api, procedure `CHANGE_CURRENT_USER_PW`

Here is an example:

```
BEGIN
APEX_UTIL.CHANGE_CURRENT_USER_PW(p_new_password => 'mysupersecretpwd');
END;
/
```

There is no way of decrypting a password or encrypting for security reasons - if you want that you'd have to create a custom authentication scheme.

In a business situation this is not common. Usually the authentication is taken care of by a central identity provider and users/passwords are not managed in the apex application.

Comment: Niccccce!!!
Thank you a lot! you are my HERO!!! :D